# moq set up class's method with multiple parameter but only take one

Tags: parameters, arguments, return, moq, matching

Hi I have tried to mock and class and set up it as followed. What ever I tried only one assert return is true. I have tired to replace Input with String and Output class with int and its works fine. Any suggestion please? Thank you very much

```
[TestFixture]
class TestSample
{
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    Mock mockObject = new Mock();
    var mockInput1 = new Mock();
    var mockInput2 = new Mock();
    var mockOutPut1 = new Mock();
    var mockOutPut2 = new Mock();
    mockObject.Setup(x => x.Get(mockInput1.Object)).Returns(mockOutPut1.Object);
    mockObject.Setup(x => x.Get(mockInput2.Object)).Returns(mockOutPut2.Object);

    var returned = mockObject.Object.Get(mockInput1.Object);
    Assert.AreEqual(mockOutPut1, returned);

    returned = mockObject.Object.Get(mockInput2.Object);
    Assert.AreEqual(mockOutPut2, returned);


    }


public class SampleClass
{
    public virtual OutputClass Get(InputClass a)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class InputClass {}
public class OutputClass {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [moq setup object parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519648/moq-setup-object-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to test here? Everything is mocked!

You should mock the class you are trying to test it!
For example, if you have a main class and a repository to get data from a databse, you should mock the repo and get fake data to use and tests your main class. But if you mock your main class and your repo, do wil not be testing anything ;)

get it? ;)